# Embedding arbitrary graph in $\mathbb Z^d$ nearest neighbor lattice

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be an arbitrary connected graph with infinitely-many vertices and bounded degree $\Delta_G$. I am interested in letting it be a directed graph ($(x,y)\in E$ not necessarily implying $(y,x)\in E$), but answering the question for an undirected graph ($(x,y)\in E$ not necessarily implies $(y,x)\in E$) would be great too.

My question is:  when such a graph can be embedded in a nearest neighbor $d$-dimensional integer lattice for some finite $d$.

I found this paper: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00493-007-2183-y from this MO thread: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440451/embedding-a-graph-into-euclidean-space.

This is not my field, so it is quite opaque to me, and I want to understand if this paper says the following.

> Let $G=(V,E)$ be an arbitrary connected graph with infinitely-many vertices and bounded degree $\Delta_G$. There is an embedding of $G$ as a subgraph of the nearest neighbor integer lattice $\mathbb Z^d$, for some finite $d$. Let $\mathsf{dim}(G)$ be the smallest $d$ for which this is possible.

If it exists, let $G'=(V',E')$ be such an embedding. Then, for all $(x,y)\in E$, we have them mapped to $(x',y')\in E'$ with $d(x',y')=1$.

It seems like that paper proves such an embedding exists at some finite $d$ for a graph with *finite growth rate*?

Here are some relevant statements from that paper:
Let $\rho_G$ be the growth rate of graph $G$, which is the minimum $\rho$ such that every ball of radius $r>1$ in $G$ contains at most $r^\rho$ vertices. The ball here is defined by the shorted path metric. They show that $\mathsf{dim}(G)=\Omega(\rho_G \log \rho_G).$

Now, I can see that the number of vertices in a ball of radius $r$ for $\mathbb Z^d$ itself grows linearly in $r$. So each nearest neighbor $d$-dimensional integer lattice has a finite growth rate. But, consider the binary tree where we have a root vertex which has two child vertices, and each of those has 2 child vertices, etc. The ball of radius $r$ around the root would contain $2^{r+1}-1$ vertices. I don't think $\rho_G$ is finite for this graph. Or am I misunderstanding something?

So, it seems that an arbitrary graph might not have any such embedding for any finite $d$. But, as long as shortest path balls in the graph only grow polynomially in the radius, then such an embedding for some finite $d$ will exist.

Later on in the paper they talk about trees with a finite growth rate, but I can't quite decipher it. It seems that, for that to occur, the number of child vertices must generally decrease sufficiently fast so that the number of vertices in the ball of radius $r$ grows polynomial in $r$. Does any of this sound reasonable?

Comment: The graph $\mathbb Z^d_\infty$ in the paper is *not* a nearest-neighbor lattice; they draw an edge $uv$ whenever $\|u-v\|_\infty \le 1$, so $u$ and $v$ can differ in any number of coordinates (but by at most $1$). If we only draw an edge from a vertex to its $2d$ nearest neighbors, then we cannot even embed all finite graphs (the simplest restriction is that the result is bipartite, so we can only embed bipartite graphs).

Comment: But yes, you are right that bounded-degree infinite graphs can still have an infinite growth rate, and not be embeddable even in $\mathbb Z^d_\infty$ (where there are $(2r+1)^d$ vertices within distance $r$ of a given vertex).

Comment: @MishaLavrov thank your again for the graph theory insight! Also thanks for catching my misreading of their neighborhood structure.